# Analyzing Performance In Dynatrace

Tags: rest, .net-core, dynatrace

We currently have a REST API application that is deployed in an Azure VM via IIS. We used Dynatrace to monitor its performance, however there's a particular request that I'm finding hard to understand.

[image]

Based from the image above the web request took 14.9 seconds, however the request to the REST API only took 1.37 seconds. There was a self time of 13.5 seconds from IIS. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible reasons for the self time of 13.5 seconds:

1. The body of the request or response headers were quite big and the transfer of the data took most of the time. Switch to "Summary" and check the body and header size.
2. Majority of the time was spend in IIS modules (e.g. authentication, compression) before/after the request was handled. Switch to *Response Time Analysis*, there you should see the time spend in IIS modules at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I did what you said and indeed when I checked IIS modules it was the one who contributed to the 13.5-second run of IIS. 

Checking further, only one module was executed which was DOTNET_ASYNC_AWAIT. What does this mean? Why would IIS take 13.5 seconds to execute this module?